# programmatically open ngbpopover from angular 2 component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am following [this article](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover) to get bootstrap working with Angular 2. While that works as per article there is no example of how to pass the reference of the popover to a component method. All I got was an `NgbPopoverConfig` but that doesn't have the reference to open the popover.

This is my component method

```
popOpen(p : NgbPopoverConfig): void {

    p.open(); //get an error here saying no Open method on NgbPopoverConfig
 }
```

and this is my html where I am using a material 2 based input field.

```
<md-input type="email"  value=""  name="em" id="em" placement="left" ngbPopover="adfga"  popoverTitle="Popover on left" triggers="manual" #p="ngbPopover" (click)="p.Open()"  [(ngModel)]="thisModel.email" 
                          #this="ngModel">
</md-input>
```

Any documentation on how to Programatically open and close the popover from the typescript component code?  or some sample code?

I am using angular 2.1.0 with Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.5 and angular material 2.0.0-alpha.9-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. There were two things I had to do. 
First get the reference to ngbPopover

`import {NgbPopover } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover';`

and change my component method to:

```
popOpen(p : NgbPopover): void {

    p.open();  
 }
```

then register the even handler like so:

```
<md-input type="email"  value=""  name="em" id="em" placement="left" ngbPopover="adfga"  popoverTitle="Popover on left" triggers="manual" #p="ngbPopover" (blur)="edit=!edit; checkExists(p)"  [(ngModel)]="thisModel.email" 
                          #this="ngModel">
</md-input>
```

Now when I lose control of the textbox, I will have a component method called that will check if email exists and if yes, I can now use the reference of `p` to fire the `open()` method.

I would like to know more about this `edit=!edit;` Does anyone know why this creates the magic that registers the blur event?

Comment: don't you need to call popOpen from html ?

Comment: Please give complete solution / explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you mistyped: it should be `open` instead of `Open`. Javascript is case sensitive

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/xR6j9GBSkf5SNTLfneAQ?p=preview)**

Comment: Are you sure? I've added plunker

Comment: Im sorry. I meant it doesn't work from the `popOpen` method in the component.

Comment: Is there a way to open that popover in such a way that I can use it for  validation? Like for example when I lose focus of that textbox. onblur event doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that work for me

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbPopover } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-popover-triggers',
  templateUrl: './popover-triggers.html'
})
export class NgbdPopoverTriggers {
condition : boolean = true;
  openPop(popover : NgbPopover): void {
    console.log(this.condition);
    popover.isOpen() ? popover.close() : popover.open();
  }
}
```

And the HTML code for the component

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br> 



<div>
<ng-template #popContent>Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>!
<button (click)="onClickYes()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" >
  Yes
</button>
<button (click)="onClickNo()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" >
  No
</button>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #popTitle>Fancy <b>content!!</b></ng-template>
</div>

<button placement="top" [popoverTitle]="popTitle" #popover="ngbPopover"  [ngbPopover]="popContent"  triggers="manual" (click)="openPop(popover)">click me </button>
```

Comment: I think this is the complete answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you need to do to use close or open API if your environment is below:

> ng-bootstrap: 1.x.x,Angular: 5.0.2,Bootstrap CSS: 4.0.0

**in your component.ts**, you need to import 'NgbPopover':

```
import {NgbPopover } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

  openPop(p : NgbPopover): void {
    this.popover.isOpen() ? this.popover.close() : this.popover.open();
  }
```

**in your HTML template,**

```
<button #popover="ngbPopover" placement="bottom" ngbPopover="adfga"  popoverTitle="Popover on left" triggers="manual" (click)="openPop(popover)"></button>
```

However, if your environment is different, you might need to check their official document to see what changes they implement.